# Wordpress WP Mail

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I'm actually a noob on this so sorry about this question. I was actually referred into google cloud through Wordpress WP mail SMTP's tutorial to link gmail to wordpress WP. Was wondering if the OAuth Client ID + Secret Password code is considered a paid service or was it a free service (referring to after trial period)? Couldn't find any information on this and am worried if I will get charged after the trial period is over for using the OAuth credentials to link to WP email SMTP. Any expert could let me know about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you won't exceed the daily quota limit & you won't be charged

https://www.parakhjs.codes/blogs/google-apis-faq

Comment: Thank you sooo much for the help!! Really appreciate it.